# use group_by in codeigniter to get latest data

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, group-by

I am new to CodeIgniter. I have seen similar threads related my question, however  I am unable find an exact solution. I have a table 'request' which contains two columns, one with 'userId' the other one with 'requestTime' as shown below (for example).

| key | userId | requestTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | abc | 55555 |
| 5 | abc | 44444 |
| 4 | xyz | 33333 |
| 3 | abc | 22222 |
| 2 | xyz | 11111 |
| 1 | lmn | 00000 |

Here I would like to get a list of 'userId' with latest time (maximum of 'requestTime') as below.

| userId | requestTime |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 55555 |
| xyz | 33333 |
| lmn | 00000 |

I am using the following code in CodeIgniter.

```
 $this->db->order_by('request.requestTime', 'desc');
 $this->db->group_by('request.userId');
 return $this->db->get('request')->result_array();
```

The above CI code does not provide results as I expected. How can get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select_max('request.requestTime','aliasName');
$this->db->group_by('request.userId');
return $this->db->get('request')->result_array();
```

I have updated the answer.. hope it will help others as well.

Comment: I think this will sort the entire table with respect to 'requestTime', which will results all the six rows in the output. However, I am interested to see one set of data corresponds to one 'userId'.

Comment: in that case you need to use select_max('request.requestTime','aliasName');  instead of order_by() and then use group_by('request.userId');

Comment: better refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/19944180/9326828

Comment: I think it is working, I will do few more test and will update.

Comment: my updated code: $this->db->select_max('request.requestTime','aliasTime');
$this->db->group_by('request.userId');
return $this->db->get('request')->result_array();  here  'aliasTime' gives the highest time. this solves issue